# VBA Freeze Screen Updating

Tags: vba

Right off the bat, I am using Excel 2010 to run a macro, but "Screen Updating = False" is not going to work in this situation -

I have an Excel sheet with some attractive formatting where I display some stats.  I have a macro that accesses an external program (CMS) to download updated stats a few times per minute.  The macro turns off screen updating, accesses CMS, copies the data, pastes it onto another sheet in the workbook, then resumes screen updating.  The idea is a live feed of this worksheet will be broadcast to people, and the stats will appear to magically update every few seconds.

The problem I'm running into is, every time I pull the CMS data, a small loading bar window pops up in the middle of the screen.  Even though Excel Screen Updating is off, I haven't found a way to hide or move this loading bar out of the way.  I don't want the stream to have a loading bar appearing and lingering every time it updates.

What I'd like to do is freeze *Windows'* screen for a second while the data is being accessed.  Is there any built-in library I could use, or other-language script I could invoke at the start of the function to freeze the Windows display while it runs, and resume it after it's complete?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that a 'loading bar' application modal dialog is not native to Excel. Are you sure this is not a CMS issue?

Comment: It's definitely CMS that's popping the loading bar - the VBA sets an object reference to the already-running instance of CMS, and tells it to print a new report.  There doesn't appear to be anything I can do in CMS itself or in the VBA code to alter where that popup appears, so I'm looking for something that will just freeze the display completely.  But if someone did have some CMS-specific i'd gladly take it

Comment: You can import some system routines like FindWindow then hunt for the dialog on the refresh. Destroying it will probably crash the routine as the internals will not be able to write new progress increments but you could use ShowWindow(hide) (◄ not the correct syntax) to hide it or even MoveWindow to shove it completely off the desktop.

Comment: @Jeeped I think you're right, apparently there's that and the BringWindowToTop functions that might do it, i'm going to mess with that - if it works i'll let you know so you can throw it in an answer if you want to

Comment: If you are doing the research and implementation, you should self-answer this question. Likely get a few upvotes and you can mark it as the 'accepted answer' after 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

and obvously turn them back on again after your code has executed

Comment: That didn't do it unfortunately - it's not Excel that's popping the loading menu, it's CMS, which the Excel macro is operating.  There is one other popup in CMS that I was able to hide during the process, but this obnoxious little loading bar doesn't seem to have any way to hide or more it through VBA